# why the value is not being pulled from JSON in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have 2 txt fields named stuno and stuname . when i enter student no in the txtfield1 it pulls and shows the student name in the txtfield2. so here is what iam doing onload of the document iam putting the focus on txtfield1(stuno).If i dont put the focus it is pulling the Name very fine . IF i have the focus it is not pulling.Onload of the form 
i need to have focus on the txtfield1(stuno).Here is the code which i have please correct me if iam doing something wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stuno").focus();
    $("#stuno").change(function(){
            if ( jQuery.trim( $( '#stuno' ).val() ) == '' ) {               
                $('#stuname').val( '' );
                $( '#stuerr' ).text( 'Student Account Not Valid!' ) ;
            }
            else{
                  $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false}); 
                  $.getJSON("student.php",{'stuno' : $("#stuno").attr('value')},
                    function(data){                                         
                      if(data[0].status){                           
                            var labelvalue = data[0].label.split('-');
                            $("#stuname").attr("value",labelvalue[1]);  
                      }else{                          
                          $('#stuname').val( '' );
                          $( '#stuerr' ).text(data[0].label);
                      }
                      if(  $("#stuname").attr("value") ){                               
                          $( '#stuerr' ).text( '' ) ;
                     }
                   });

            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What does the JSON stuff that "student.php" returns look like? Also, the description of what's wrong does not make a lot of sense ...

Comment: @pointy:[{"label":"STU123-STUDENT1","value":"STU123","status":true}].This is how the JSOnlooks like .It is not able to pull the student name when i have the focus in the student no .if i dont have the focus it is working fine

Comment: OK, so can you describe how you would like the page to work?  Like, what should the user see when it works perfectly?  When should the "name" be loaded? Is there some popular website that behaves the way you would like your page to behave?

Comment: @pointy:when the user enter the stu number he should see student name in the student name textbox .I havent seen anykind of this in any popular website .

Comment: The "change" event is, as @betamax points out in an answer, fired only when the input field *loses* focus. If you type a number and then click somewhere else on the window, or press "tab", does that cause the name to be loaded?

Comment: @pointy:fired only when input field loses focus().I mean when we press tab it pull the name in to the stuname field

Comment: Right - that's how the "change" event works.  When would you prefer that the name be loaded?  How can your code know when the user is finished typing in the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `keypress` instead of `change`. Change is fired when you leave focus of the input or when a select box is changed. Keypress is fired whenever a key is pressed or released.

So instead of:

```
$("#stuno").change(function(){
```

use

```
$("#stuno").keypress(function(){
```

Comment: Yes but does he really want to go back to the server for every keypress?  If the student number is "10122357" ...

Comment: Yeah, I wondered that. I was just answering my interpretation of his question.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question.

You're changing between $ and jQuery which is a bit weird. Also, is there a reason why you're using `$("#stuno").attr("value") instead of $("#stuno").val()?`

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't fire the `onChange` event until focus is lost. Perhaps you'd want to do something like this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#stuno").focus().keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which === 13){ // if the enter key was pressed
            e.preventDefault() // prevent the enter key from submitting the form
            if ( $.trim( $( '#stuno' ).val() ) == '' ) {
                $('#stuname').val( '' );
                $( '#stuerr' ).text( 'Student Account Not Valid!' ) ;
            }
            else{
                $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false}); 
                $.getJSON("student.php",{'stuno' : $("#stuno").val()},
                    function(data){                                  
                        if(data[0].status){                           
                            var labelvalue = data[0].label.split('-');
                            $("#stuname").val(labelvalue[1]);  
                        }else{                          
                            $('#stuname').val( '' );
                            $( '#stuerr' ).text(data[0].label);
                        }
                        if(  $("#stuname").val() ){                               
                          $( '#stuerr' ).text( '' ) ;
                     }
                   });

            }
        }
    });
});
```

I've done a few things to your code. I changed all `.attr('value',...)` calls to `.val()` for consistency. And I've used the `jQuery` variable on the outside of your ready function and ensure that the `$` variable is in fact jQuery inside your ready function. And I've changed your `change` handler to run on [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) only if the key pressed was the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: The Behaviour is the Same there is no change.

Comment: Strange. Here's some slight re-working of that code above working great for keypress (enter) and not working at all for change: http://jsfiddle.net/sholsinger/9CfxL/13/

Comment: Oh I should mention that you need to press the [Enter] key for my code to request the JSON from your PHP script.